# multicore application cygwin

Tags: cygwin, multicore

If I run a parallized application (using f.e. OpenMP) on a windows multicore within cygwin - do I have the full multicore performance the windows machine is offering or is there a significant speed reduction to expect due to the cygwin layer?

Any experiences?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but in light of my recent findings about a Cygwin bug on multithreaded apps on multicore CPUs ([see my bug report on the Cygwin mailing list](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2012-08/msg00200.html)), I just want to point out that multithreaded applications on Cygwin is a no go. In my case, a multithreaded application on a dual core runs 8x slower than if you force it to run on single core (via setting CPU affinity mask).